# Convert numbers to arabic in Canavsjs charts

Tags: charts, canvasjs

I'm making a bar chart using Canavsjs from here http://canvasjs.com/

and this is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/samehsubscription/DqM2u/

i need to convert the numbers in y to arabic & in the tooltip too !
i'm using function called

```
    function arNum(numb) {
    var str = numb.toString();

    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(str.toString())) {
        str = str.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }

    var arabic = { "0": '٠', "1": '١', "2": '٢', "3": '٣', "4": '٤', "5": '٥', "6": '٦', "7": '٧', "8": '٨', "9": '٩' };
    var chars = str.split("");
    var newnum = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] == ",") newnum[i] = ",";
        else
            newnum[i] = arabic[chars[i]];
    }

    return newnum.join("");
}
```

i used this function with D3 and it is working perfectly but i can't implement it in canavsjs

thanx for any help